# Remove parameters in search query (only use specific query)?

Tags: php, laravel-5

A typical search query: https://mywebsite.ph/search?searchItem=marketing&criteria=bachelorsdegree&search=Search+Courses

This is the search query I want to have: https://mywebsite.ph/search?searchLocation=Manila

Note: mywebsite.ph is NOT my website.....I just put it there for the sake of my question.

If I remove "searchItem", "criteria", and "search=" from the query, the page breaks and I get an error.  example of error:

Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::where(), called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1470 and defined

The search query is built using this controller file:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\posts;

 use App\categories;

 use App\schools;

 use DB;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;

 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;

 class searchController extends Controller
 {
protected $result = [];

public function articlesearch(Request $request){

    $searchItem=$request['searchItem'];
    $searchLocation=$request['searchLocation'];

    $criteria=$request['criteria'];

    if($criteria == 'articles'){

        $result=posts::whereRaw("MATCH(title,content,keywords) AGAINST('$searchItem')")->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('articles', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem);  

        }

        else{

            return view('articles')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria));

        }

    }

}

public function postsearch(Request $request)
{
    $searchItem=$request['searchItem'];
    $searchLocation=$request['searchLocation'];

    $criteria=$request['criteria'];
    $search = "";
    if($request['search'] == "Search Colleges"){
        $search = "SearchColleges";
    }else{
        $search = "SearchCourses";
    }

    $fees = schools::where('status','')
    ->orderBy('fees', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('fees')
    ->toArray();

    $fees = array_unique($fees);
    $priceRanges = array();

    $minPrice = 0;
    $maxPrice = 0;
    if(count($fees) > 0){
        foreach ($fees as $key => $value) {
            $range = explode(' - ', $value);
            $priceRanges[] = $range['0'];
            //$priceRanges[] = $range['1'];
        }
        $priceRanges = array_unique($priceRanges);
        $minPrice = (int) min($priceRanges);
        $maxPrice = (int) max($priceRanges);
    }

    if($criteria == 'schools'){

    //       $result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
        $result=schools::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
    //  ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->where('status','')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();


        $this->result = $result;

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count,'search'=>$search))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));

        }

    }



    if($criteria == 'articles'){

        $result=posts::whereRaw("MATCH(title,content,keywords) AGAINST('$searchItem')")->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('articles', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,

                'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count,'title' => 'SchoolDir Articles','search'=>$search,

                'cat' => categories::where('status','')->get()))

            ->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));    

        }

        else{

            return view('articles')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search,'title' => 'SchoolDir Articles'))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));

        }

    }



    if($criteria == 'bachelorsdegree'){

    //return redirect()->back();    
    //$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(undergradcourses) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();

    //      $result=schools::where('undergradcourses', 'LIKE', '__'.$searchItem.'__')
    //                 ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '__'.$searchLocation.'__')
    //                 ->where('status','')->get();
        $result=schools::where('undergradcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
    //  ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->where('status','')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem, 'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));   

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'search'=>$search,'criteria'=>$criteria))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));
        }

    }



    if($criteria == 'mastersdegree'){

    //return redirect()->back();    
    //$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(postgradcourses) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
    //      $result=schools::where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchItem.'___')
    //                 ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchLocation.'___')
    //                 ->where('status','')->get();
        $result=schools::where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
    //  ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->where('status','')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem, 'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));   

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'search'=>$search,'criteria'=>$criteria))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));
        }

    }



    if($criteria == 'technicalvocational'){

    //return redirect()->back();    
    //$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(technicalandvocationalcourses) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
    //      $result=schools::where('technicalandvocationalcourses', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchItem.'___')
    //                 ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchLocation.'___')
    //                 ->where('status','')->get();
        $result=schools::where('technicalandvocationalcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
    //  ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->where('status','')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem, 'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));   

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'search'=>$search,'criteria'=>$criteria))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));
        }

    }



    if($criteria == 'certificateshortcourse'){

    //return redirect()->back();    
    //$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(shortcoursesandcertifications) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
    //      $result=schools::where('shortcoursesandcertifications', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchItem.'___')
    //                 ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchLocation.'___')
    //                 ->where('status','')->get();
        $result=schools::where('shortcoursesandcertifications', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
    //  ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->where('status','')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem, 'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));   

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'search'=>$search,'criteria'=>$criteria))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));
        }

    }

    if($criteria == ''){

    //return redirect()->back();    
    //$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(shortcoursesandcertifications) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
    //      $result=schools::where('shortcoursesandcertifications', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchItem.'___')
    //                 ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '___'.$searchLocation.'___')
    //                 ->where('status','')->get();
        $result=schools::where()
    //  ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->where('status','')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem, 'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));   

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'search'=>$search,'criteria'=>$criteria))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));
        }

    }

}   

//sort search

public function sortsearch(Request $request){



    $input = $request->all();

    $fees = schools::where('status','')
    ->orderBy('fees', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('fees')
    ->toArray();


    $ranking_philippines = schools::where('status','')
    ->orderBy('ranking_philippines', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('ranking_philippines')
    ->toArray();

    $fees = array_unique($fees);
    $priceRanges = array();
    $minPrice = 0;
    $maxPrice = 0;

    if(count($fees) > 0){
        foreach ($fees as $key => $value) {
            $range = explode(' - ', $value);
            $priceRanges[] = $range['0'];
            //$priceRanges[] = $range['1'];
        }
        $priceRanges = array_unique($priceRanges);
        $minPrice = (int) (min($priceRanges)?min($priceRanges):0);
        $maxPrice = (int) (max($priceRanges)?max($priceRanges):0);          
    }

    $ranking_philippines = array_unique($ranking_philippines);
    $rankings = array();
    $minRank = 0;
    $maxRank = 0;

    if(count($ranking_philippines) > 0){
        foreach ($ranking_philippines as $key => $value) {
            $range = explode("  ", $value);
            $rankings[] = $range['0'];
            $rankings[] = isset($range['1']) ? $range['1'] : null;
        }
        $rankings = array_unique($rankings);
        $minRank = (int) (min($rankings)?min($rankings):0);
        $maxRank = (int) (max($rankings)?max($rankings):0);                                             
    }



    ##--- Search begins
    $searchItem = str_replace("%", " ", $request['searchItem']);

    $searchLocation = $request['searchLocation'];

    $criteria = $request['criteria'];

    $ownership = $request['ownership'];
    //$centers_of_excellence=str_replace(" ", "%", $request['centers_of_excellence']);
            // changed by Suraj k 3-4-18;
    // center of ex is an array in view/ filters; please see the view file;
    $coe = $request['centers_of_excellence'];
    $centers_of_excellence = "";
    if(is_array($coe) && isset($coe[0])){
        $centers_of_excellence = str_replace(" ", "%", $coe[0]);
    }
    ##--


    $city = $request['city']; // array in view file
    $type = $request['type']; // array in view file
    $term_structure = $request['term_structure']; // array in view file



    $Ranges = array();
    if (isset($request['FeesRange']) && !empty($request['FeesRange'])) {
        $Ranges = explode(' - ',$request['FeesRange']);
    }else{
        $Ranges = explode(' - ',$request['fees']);
    }

    $Ranking = array();
    if (isset($request['PhilippinesRanking']) && !empty($request['PhilippinesRanking'])) {
        $Ranking = explode(" ",$request['PhilippinesRanking']);
    }else{
        $Ranking = explode(" ",$request['ranking_philippines']);
    }

    $returnData['Ranges'] = $Ranges;
    $returnData['Ranking'] = $Ranking;
    $returnData['sortby'] = $request['sortby'];
    $returnData['rankingsortby'] = $request['rankingsortby'];
    $returnData['PhilippinesRanking'] = $request['PhilippinesRanking'];
    $returnData['FeesRange'] = $request['FeesRange'];
    //dd($Rfees);
    $sortby=isset($request['sortby'])?trim($request['sortby']):'';
    $rankingsortby=isset($request['rankingsortby'])?trim($request['rankingsortby']):'';
    $search=$request['search'];
    //dd($fees);
    //$type=$request['School_type'];

    //$location=$request['location'];       
    //$result = schools::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%');
    //dd($result);
    //$result = schools::where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%')->orwhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%')->orwhere('describtion', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');

    // changed by Suraj k. 4 Apr 2018
    $result = NULL;

    if ($criteria == 'schools') {
        $result = schools::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
    } elseif ($criteria == 'bachelorsdegree') {
        $result = schools::where('undergradcourses', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
    } elseif ($criteria == 'mastersdegree') {
        $result = schools::where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
    } elseif ($criteria == 'technicalvocational') {
        $result = schools::where('technicalandvocationalcourses', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
    } elseif ($criteria == 'certificateshortcourse') {
        $result = schools::where('shortcoursesandcertifications', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchItem . '%');
    } elseif ($criteria == '') {
        $result = schools::where();
    }


    if (!empty($searchLocation)) {

        $result = $result->where('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchLocation . '%');

    }
    elseif(!empty($city)) {

        $result = $result->where('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%');

    }


    if (!empty($type)) {

        $result = $result->where('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $type . '%');

    }

    if (!empty($term_structure)) {

        $result = $result->where('term_structure', 'LIKE', '%' . $term_structure . '%');

    }

    ##-- changed by Suraj k. 4 Apr 2018

            if (sizeof($Ranges) > 1) {
                        $result = $result->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', 1)"), '>=', (int) $Ranges[0])
                                 ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, ' - ', -1)"), '<=', (int) $Ranges[1]);
            }

    if (sizeof($Ranking) > 1) {
        $result = $result->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, '  ', 1)"), '>=', (int) $Ranking[0])
                         ->where(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(fees, '  ', -1)"), '<=', (int) $Ranking[1]);
    }

    if($ownership){

        $result = $result->whereIn('ownership', $ownership);

    }
    //if($city){
    //  $result = $result->whereIn('city',$city);
    //}
    // changed by suraj k 4 apr 18
    if($criteria == $centers_of_excellence && !empty($centers_of_excellence) ){

        $result = $result->whereRaw("( centers_of_excellence LIKE '%$centers_of_excellence%' ) ");

    }
    //if($type){
    //  $result = $result->whereIn('type',$type);
    //}
    //if($criteria == $term_structure){
    //  $result = $result->where('term_structure', '=', $term_structure);
    //}
    //if($term_structure){
    //  $result = $result->whereIn('term_structure',$term_structure);
    //}

    /*
    // changed by suraj k. 4 Apr 18
    if (is_array($city) && count($city) > 0) {


        $tq = array();

        foreach ($city as $c) {

            $tq[] = "city LIKE '%$c%'";
            break;
        }

        $c_str = implode(' OR ', $tq);

        if (!empty($c_str)) {

            $c_str = " (" . $c_str . ")";

            $result->whereRaw("$c_str");

        }

    }


    // changed by suraj k. 4 Apr 18
    if (is_array($type) && count($type) > 0) {

        $tq = array();

        foreach ($type as $ty) {

            $tq[] = "term_structure LIKE '%$ty%'";
            break;
        }

        $type_str = implode(' OR ', $tq);

        //dd($type_str);

        if (!empty($type_str)) {

            $type_str = " (" . $type_str . ")";

            $result->whereRaw("$type_str");

        }

    }

    // changed by suraj k. 4 Apr 18
    if (is_array($term_structure) && count($term_structure) > 0) {

        $tq = array();

        foreach ($term_structure as $ts) {

            $tq[] = "term_structure LIKE '%$ts%'";
            break;

        }

        $term_str = implode(' OR ', $tq);

        //dd($type_str);

        if(!empty($term_str)) {

            $term_str = " (". $term_str .")";

            $result->whereRaw("$term_str");

        }

    }
    */

            if($sortby != ""){
                if($sortby == "HightoLow"){
                        $result = $result->orderBy('fees', 'asc');
                }else{
                        $result = $result->orderBy('fees', 'desc');
                }
            }

            if($rankingsortby != ""){
                if($rankingsortby == "HightoLow"){
                        //$result = $result->orderByRaw('convert(ranking_philippines,unsigned) asc');
                        $result = $result->orderByRaw('convert((CASE WHEN ranking_philippines IS NULL then 129999999999999 ELSE ranking_philippines END),unsigned) asc');
                }else{
                        //$result = $result->orderByRaw('convert(ranking_philippines,unsigned) desc');
                        $result = $result->orderByRaw('convert((CASE WHEN ranking_philippines IS NULL then 0 ELSE ranking_philippines END),unsigned) desc');
                }
            }

    $result = $result->get();



    if(count($result)>0){

        $count=count($result);

        return view('schools', [
            'result' => $result,
            'searchItem' => $searchItem,
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'count' => $count, 
            'searchLocation' => $searchLocation,
            'search' => $search,
            'minPrice' => $minPrice,
            'maxPrice' => $maxPrice,
            'minRank' => $minRank,
            'maxRank' => $maxRank,
            'returnData' => $returnData
        ]);

    }

    else{

        return view('schools', [
            'msg' => 'No result found',
            'count' => '0',
            'searchItem' => str_replace("%", " ", $searchItem),
            'criteria' => $criteria, 
            'searchLocation' => $searchLocation,
            'search' => $search,
            'minRank' => $minRank,
            'maxRank' => $maxRank,
            'returnData' => $returnData
        ]);

    }
}





 }
```

The search query CAN work even without some of the queries used in the FILTER box such as "city=" or "type=".  But how I can I make it work using only specific queries such as "searchLocation"?

My search form code:

```
   <!-- Tab links -->
        <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openCity(event, 'Search by Course')">Search by Course</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Search by College')">Search by College</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Tab content -->
        <div style="width:100%;height: 130px;" id="Search by Course" class="tabcontent form-group col-md-6">
            <form action="{{ action("searchController@postsearch") }}" method="get" role="form" style="padding-top: 3%;" class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-25">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchItem" placeholder="eg: Marketing" required>
            </div>
     <!--       <div class="col-30">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchLocation" placeholder="Location" >
            </div> -->
               <div class="col-md-4 col-20">
                <select style="height: 40px;background: #e6e6e6;width:100%;border: 0px solid #ccc;" class="" name="criteria" required>
                    <option selected="selected" value="bachelorsdegree">Bachelors Degree</option>
                    <option value="mastersdegree">Masters Degree</option>
                    <option value="technicalvocational">Technical/Vocational</option>
                    <option value="certificateshortcourse">Certificate/Short Course</option>
                </select>
                </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-2 form-button">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-search" name="search" value="Search Courses">
            </div> 
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="Search by College" style="width:100%;height: 130px;" class="tabcontent form-group col-md-6">
            <form action="{{ action("searchController@postsearch") }}" method="get" role="form" style="padding-top: 3%;" class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-25">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchItem" placeholder="eg: University of the Philippines" required>
            </div>
        <!--    <div class="col-30">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchLocation" placeholder="Location">
            </div> -->
               <div class="col-md-4 col-20">
                <select style="height: 40px;background: #e6e6e6;width:100%;border: 0px solid #ccc;" class="" name="criteria" required>
                    <option selected="selected" value="schools">Schools</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 form-button">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-search" name="search" value="Search Colleges">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Now that's a lot of code ...

Comment: @kerbholz - yea, stackoverlow users LOVE seeing code and complain when code is not provided to support the question being posted sooooo there ya go.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this on my own with help from someone:

Added this code right above `if($criteria == 'schools'){` and below

```
            $maxPrice = (int) max($priceRanges);
    }
```

Code:

```
    if($searchLocation != ""){
        $result=schools::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();


        $this->result = $result;

        if(count($result)>0){

            $count=count($result);

            return view('schools', array('result' => $result, 'msg' => ''))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count,'search'=>$search))->with('searchItem',$searchItem)->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));

        }

        else{

            return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'search'=>$search))->with(array('minPrice' =>$minPrice,'maxPrice'=>$maxPrice));

        }

    }
```

Added `'msg' => ''` to the `return view` statement in all controller files.